# Is $\partial (\liminf_{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}a_{t})/\partial a_{t} = 1$ for every $t \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, applications

If we do not impose any conditions on the real sequence $(a_{t})$ other than that $a_{t} \geq 0$ for all $t$, is it necessarily true that for every $t \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\partial (\liminf_{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}a_{t})/\partial a_{t} = 1$? The function under consideration is $(a_{1},a_{2},\dots) \mapsto \liminf_{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}a_{t}$.

Answer (score 2):

Because $\liminf_{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}a_{t}$ doesn't depend on any particular $a_n$, it only depends on the sequence as a whole, we get that

$$\partial (\liminf_{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}a_{t})/\partial a_{n} = 0$$

Comment: My bad. A typo corrected.

Comment: The current expression doesn't really make sense right now because you have $t$ both as a variable in the sum (which is inside the differentiation) and as an index of the variable with respect to which you differentiate.

Comment: I guess you are seeing it from the view of pure math! Just view it in terms of applied math! For example: $\partial(a_{1}+a_{2})/\partial a_{1} = 1$.

Comment: @GaryMoore: exactly: what you wrote in your question is $\partial(a_1+a_2)/\partial a_t$, which makes no sense.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, meaning $t = 1,2$. Just take it "intuitively" :).

Comment: $t$ should be a constant as the index of differentiation, but you also make it a changing variable in the sum ( it goes from $1$ to $n$), that's why your expression doesn't make sense.

Comment: @wilkersmon, see if you feel better now.

Comment: You just added "for every $t \in \mathbb{N}$" which still doesn't fix the problem as you're double defining it and it makes it meaningless.

Comment: @wilkersmon, okay now I think the "conversation" should be stopped. Please leave this question alone.

Comment: I was just trying to help you formulate the question so that it actually makes sense but ok

Comment: This is stack exchange **mathematics**. Please don't pollute the site, and don't downvote people reminding you that this should be about mathematics. Thank you.